# Git rebase for deleting commits from remote

Tags: git

Ok I have read a couple of posts here on `git revert` vs `git rebase` vs `cherry-pick` etc. I just want to make sure I get it right before applying it.

I have two branches, master and develop.

Master was at commit with id 1.
Develop was at commit with id 10 let's say. (assuming they go linearly so 2 ,3,...,9,10 are only on develop).

Merging develop to Master. But then I realised that I didn't want to merge from that point. But only until id 7.

A. How do I remove id's 8,9,10? A simple `git rebase` will do right? Will it cause issues in the future when I try to merge develop back again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have nothing else in `master` that you don't want to lose since you merged:

1. Reset your local `master` to the point before the merge (id 1?): `git reset --hard id1`
2. Merge from id 7: `git merge id7`
3. Force-push it to the server: `git push origin master` (The usual implications of force-pushing apply.)

After this, if you want to merge ids 8, 9, 10 later, you can.

Comment: The usual implications of force-pushing apply.